# SQL for simple relevance ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have 3 tables: person_tag (person_id, tag), interest_tag (interest_id, tag), skill_tag (skill_id, tag). Much as I would like to have one tag table for interest and skill, I need to keep them separate. Sample data below:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| person_id | tag         |   
+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | x           |
| 1         | y           |
| 1         | z           |
+-----------+-------------+

+-------------+-------------+
| interest_id | tag         |   
+-------------+-------------+
| 10          | x           |
| 20          | y           |
| 20          | z           |
+-------------+-------------+

+-------------+-------------+
| skill_id    | tag         |   
+-------------+-------------+
| 100         | x           |
| 100         | y           |
| 100         | z           |
| 900         | a           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I would like to write a query that would return a result like the following in terms of relevance for a given person_id (e.g., 1). Notice "a" does not appear in the results below:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id          | typ         | score       |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 100         | skill       | 3           |
| 20          | interest    | 2           |
| 10          | interest    | 1           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I suspect UNION will be my friend here, but not quite sure how to write the query. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` with `group by` expressions

```
select skill_id , 'skill' as typ, count( skill_id ) as score 
  from skill_tag 
 group by skill_id
union all
select interest_id , 'interest' as typ, count(interest_id) as score 
  from interest_tag 
 group by interest_id
 order by score desc
```

P.S. By the way, You don't need `person_tag` table.

Comment: I think you got it. My question was a bit flawed in that I didn't request that you take into account only tags that were shared by the person_tag table. But I think it's an easy change to what you suggested (e.g., from skill_tag where tag in (select tag from person where id = ?) or I could do a join), so that we only get tags relevant  to a given person. Also, I think I need to order the results in desc order based on count, but that's easy as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes union will work

```
select interest_id as id,count(*) as score, 'Interest' as typ from interest group by interest_id
union
select skill_id as id,count(*) as score, 'Skill' as typ from skill group by skill_id;
```